# Firebase Document for each user?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am wondering how to make a document for each user as they create their account (with Firebase Web). I have Firebase Authentication enabled and working, and I'd like each user then to have a document in Cloud Firestore in a collection named users. How would I get the UID and then automatically create a document for each user? (I am doing this so that calendar events can be saved into an array field in the document, but I need a document for the user to start with). I am aware and know how to make security rules for access, I just don't know how to make the document in the first place.
Thanks!

Comment: you can do that with firebase functions, auth triggers :)

Comment: Small addition to @DauleDK's (very good :) ) suggestion: here is the link to the doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

Comment: How would I implement this with Cloud Firestore (not Realtime Database)"?

Comment: @NeeronBhatta This sample shows how to write to Firestore from a Cloud Function: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/9ce5109babd4f3b240d097debdc570dbe7383682/quickstarts/uppercase-firestore/functions/index.js You should combine the code from the two links.

Comment: @NeeronBhatta Also, I would suggest that you have a look at these three videos from the Firebase team:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=517s &

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk&t=27s &

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9GrysWH1Lc. A must for anyone starting coding for Cloud Functions. Good luck :-) !

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out combining the code tomorrow :) Looks good just skimming through it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While it is definitely possible to create a user profile document through Cloud Functions, as Renaud and guillefd suggest, also consider creating the document directly from your application code. The approach is fairly similar, e.g. if you're using email+password sign-in:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(function(user) {
    // get user data from the auth trigger
    const userUid = user.uid; // The UID of the user.
    const email = user.email; // The email of the user.
    const displayName = user.displayName; // The display name of the user.

    // set account  doc  
    const account = {
      useruid: userUid,
      calendarEvents: []
    }
    firebase.firestore().collection('accounts').doc(userUid).set(account); 
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });
```

Aside from running directly from the web app, this code also creates the document with the user's UID as the key, which makes subsequent lookups a bit simpler.

Comment: I imagine this would require a user to have permission to create documents in the accounts collection?

Comment: @holmberd yep, this can handle it: `match /accounts/{uid} {allow read, write: if uid == request.auth.uid;}`

Answer (score 14):

You´ll have to set a firebase function triggered by the [onCreate() Auth trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation).
1. create the function trigger
2. get the user created data
3. set the account data.
4. add the account data to the collection.

**functions/index.js**

```
// Firebase function 

exports.createAccountDocument = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // get user data from the auth trigger
  const userUid = user.uid; // The UID of the user.
  //const email = user.email; // The email of the user.
  //const displayName = user.displayName; // The display name of the user.

  // set account  doc  
  const account = {
    useruid: userUid,
    calendarEvents: []
  }
  // write new doc to collection
  return admin.firestore().collection('accounts').add(account); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Firebase UI](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web) to simplify your life a lil, you can add a User document to a "/users" collection in Firestore **only** when that user *first* signs up by using `authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser` from the `signInSuccessWithAuthResult` in your UI config.

I'm doing something like this in my project:

```js
let uiConfig = {
...
  callbacks: {
    signInSuccessWithAuthResult: (authResult) => {
      // this is a new user, add them to the firestore users collection!
      if (authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
        db.collection("users")
          .doc(authResult.user.uid)
          .set({
            displayName: authResult.user.displayName,
            photoURL: authResult.user.photoURL,
            createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          })
          .then(() => {
            console.log("User document successfully written!");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error writing user document: ", error);
          });
      }
      return false;
    },
  },
...
}
...
ui.start("#firebaseui-auth-container", uiConfig);
```

The `signInSuccessWithAuthResult` gives you an `authResult` and a `redirectUrl`.

*from the [Firebase UI Web Github README](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web):*

```js
// ...
signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
  // If a user signed in with email link, ?showPromo=1234 can be obtained from
  // window.location.href.
  // ...
  return false;
}
```