# Does Firestore's auth.user().onCreate trigger complete before auth().createUser?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to know if when you call await auth.createUser(), does all of the code in the auth.user().onCreate trigger complete along with this so that after my call to createUser() I can immediately query data that would have been set in the onCreate trigger?

**Clarification:**
Thanks for the replies so far. Unfortunately, it's a bit more complicated than both of those answers. The scenario is that I have created a multi-app, multi-project system in Firebase that allows a user to sign up for an account in one of multiple different mobile apps and they all get linked to one central account on the "Main Project".

Each project, including the "Main Project", has one auth user for the user as well as a user document created in Firestore.

Now, if they are a completely new user to the platform, the onCreate trigger of "App X/Project X" handles creating the auth user account on the "Main Project" by calling createUser() in the onCreate of "App X/Project X". In the onCreate of the "Main Project" for the auth user, the user document on "Main Project" gets initialized and I'd like to access that data directly after calling createUser() for "Main Project" from "App X/Project X".

It's a complicated scenario but I simply want to know if the code in onCreate for the auth user of the "Main Project" will certainly complete along with createUser() being called from "App X/Project X" so that "App X/Project X" can immediately access the user document of the "Main Project"  which is initialized in the onCreate of the auth user for the "Main Project".

It's all setup and working as expected, but the scenario that I am worried about is if the onCreate of the auth user on the "Main Project" does not **necessairly** complete before createUser() is called on "App X/Project X" so that "App X/Project X" will then try to access and update data of the "Main Project" user document when it hasn't yet been initialized.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Firebase Document for each user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50087067/7725879)? That's just an example to show you that you can actually create a user and then setting their data in a document. Please refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) for further details.

Comment: @sllopis i have updated my question with further details.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no, onCreate does not complete before createUser() completes. createUser() finishes before the onCreate trigger completes. Tested by checking timestamps logged at the end of the onCreate trigger and after the createUser() call.