# At what point during FirebaseUI auth process can I access user credentials?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, next.js

Referring to this official [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086515/firebase-document-for-each-user) from the Next.js github that shows using firebase auth with next.

Many projects I study, at some point use createUserWithEmailAndPassword. With this they can **use the user credentials to do things like creating a new document in a 'users' collection in a firestore database. [This stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086515/firebase-document-for-each-user) and this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWy9ylc3f9U) refer to this method.

The example I linked to, (i think) uses firebase-ui - the auth part of my code looks like this:

```
const firebaseAuthConfig = {
  signInFlow: 'popup',
  // Auth providers
  // https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#configure-oauth-providers
  signInOptions: [
    {
      requireDisplayName: true,
      provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      
    },
  ],
  signInSuccessUrl: '/',
  credentialHelper: 'none',
  callbacks: {
    signInSuccessWithAuthResult: async ({ user }, redirectUrl) => {


      

      const userData = mapUserData(user)
      setUserCookie(userData)

     

    },
  },
}


const FirebaseAuth = () => {
  // Do not SSR FirebaseUI, because it is not supported.
  // https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/213
  const [renderAuth, setRenderAuth] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      setRenderAuth(true)
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      {renderAuth ? (
        <StyledFirebaseAuth
          uiConfig={firebaseAuthConfig}
          firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}
        />
      ) : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the same thing using the `callbacks: {}` during auth? Is there another way I should be getting access to user credentials and passing to a firestore collection? (I'm trying to do this in my application code rather than as a cloud function.)

I also notice that usually, I see this: `signInSuccessWithAuthResult: async(authResult) => {}` - where as the example project has `signInSuccessWithAuthResult: async ({ user }, redirectUrl) => {}`

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no need to "get access to user credentials".  The only thing you need to be concerned about is making sure you perform any Firebase queries **after** the user has signed in.  It doesn't matter how they sign in.

You can detect when a user signs in by using an [auth state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data).  The observer callback will let you know when a user has signed in.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
  }
});
```

When the callback is invoked and is provided a user object, that's when you can query the database with the privileges assigned to the user.  You don't have to "pass information to Firestore" to let it know about the signed-in user.  That happens automatically if you're using the Firebase SDKs for both Auth and Firestore.